# Modifying method in parent theme class via child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

After a lot of trial and error and research i am back to square one.
Simply put what i am trying to do is edit a function which is inside a class in the parent theme via child themes function.php, however the class itself is not pluggable :(.

Can someone give me correct way to overrite a class via child theme? Is it even possible on a non pluggable class?

The class itself extends another class and the base class IS PLUGGABLE.

```
class Fre_ReviewAction extends AE_Base --> Class attempting to overrite
----------------------------------
if (!class_exists('AE_Base')) {
class AE_Base --> Base class IS PLUGGABLE?
```

Can it be rewritten via child theme functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that , first you need to remove the action which you have used in the parent/base class.

```
function remove_add_class_actions() {
  //remove some action stuff , for example I used woocommerce action
  remove_action( 'some_action_hook', array( $GLOBALS['someglobals'], 'functiontooverrideinchildclass' ), 10, 3 );

  //add action by child class m in your case it will be Fre_ReviewAction
  add_action( 'some_action_hook', array(  new Fre_ReviewAction, 'functiontooverrideinchildclass' ) );
}

add_action( 'init','remove_add_class_actions' );
```

After that you need define the child class extending parent,

```
class Fre_ReviewAction extends AE_Base {
  function __construct() {
    //parent::__construct();
  }

  function functiontooverrideinchildclass(){
    //your stuff here
  }

}
```

Comment: I do not understand how to apply this does all this go to the functions.php?

Comment: And i cannot find the an action to remove as well